# Solaris 10: how to enable some cipher or esclude weak cipher on ssh?

Tags: ssh, solaris

On HPUX and Linux servers this line works fine

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128
```

On solaris10 give me error

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 155: Bad SSH2 cipher spec 'aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128'
```

I'm sure ssh on solaris support those ciphers

Comment: `Ssh -v` on both gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arcfour128 and arcfour256 are not supported by Sun SSH on Solaris 10.

Try:

```
ssh -c arcfour256 somehost
```

You'll likely get:
Unknown cipher type 'arcfour256'

You will need to remove them from your Ciphers list.  Alternately, install OpenSSH if you really need them.